# Adding up data from a specific column in the database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have these data from a table. Example, I have table for points named tbl_points.
tbl_points contains :

```
ptsID, team1, team2.
1       10      20
2       20      10
3       30      5
```

How do I create a query that will sum up the points for team1 and team2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(team1) AS team1_points, 
  SUM(team2) AS team2_points
FROM
  tbl_points
```

will give you an one-row table as result:

```
| team1_points | team2_points |
| 60           | 35           |
```

Also, using name `tbl_points` is not good. It's better to use no prefixes. Just name your table `points`, it will be clear enough.

Comment: @jetoox, Riateche has good point to don't use prefix of "tbl_"... its obvious querying from the table... Also head caution of column names to NOT use things that might be "reserved words", like Date, Name, Time, Count, Group, etc...

Comment: @DRapp using tbl as prefix is already part of our coding convention. and what are you ranting about using reserved words? Did i even use it above?

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
   SELECT SUM(p1.team1) AS team1_score
        , SUM(p2.team2) AS team2_score
     FROM tbl_points AS p1
        , tbl_points AS p2
```